# react-snap: getting "processGoogleToken is not defined" error

Tags: reactjs, prerender, server-side-rendering, react-snap

I'm trying to populate static pages from a react app using react-snap and I keep getting this error on every page.

I don't find anything online on this error, same with "VM1516 integrator.js".

Any idea what's causing this?

[image: processGoogleToken error]

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this?

Comment: Nope, still getting those

Comment: I'm seeing something similar with Scully (Angular SSG).

Answer (score 3):

If you add to your package.json file it will stop google adsense/analytics from loading. Warnings about failed network requests will show instead of the error.

```
  "reactSnap": {
    "skipThirdPartyRequests": true
  }
```

The other option is you can dynamically load the google script based on the user agent.

```
  if (navigator.userAgent !== "ReactSnap") {
    // some code to dynamically load a script
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using Google Analytics and/or Google Adsense scripts.

**react-snap** executed them locally and put the partial response into the snapshots :(

Comment: Any solution to this?